# Make a regular expression in the search in VS code

Tags: python, django, regex, visual-studio-code

I'd like to change the img html tag to django html with `{%static`.

Can you make a regular expression in the *ctrl + f* function so I can change it at once?

Example:

`<img src="../img/logo.png"` => `<img src=" {%static 'img/logo.png' %}"`

```
r'<img\s+src="(.*?)"'
```

But I can't find a way to change the code while preserving the middle values

Comment: Likely not: HTML is a context-free language, so a lot (most) of tasks can not be handled completely with a regular expression.

Comment: it is shown in [Case changing in regex replace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_case-changing-in-regex-replace) to use `$n`, it should have been more prominent where they show Regex Search and Replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a *backreference*:

search query: `<img\s+src="[.][.]/([^"]*)"`
replace with: `<img src="{% static '$1' %}"`

The `$1` will then be replaced with the first *capture group*.

That being said, HTML is a context-free language. That means most tasks can not be handled (perfectly) with a regular expression. For example the regex we here make does not take into accounts attributes before the `src=""` attribute. Likely a tool like BeautifulSoup is therefore a better idea.